# Асинхронный бесконечный цикл в python

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio

У меня есть цикл. Он выполняется бесконечно.

```
while True:
    ...
```

Можно ли как-нибудь запустить этот цикл асинхронно? То есть у меня параллельно будет запущен flask. И чтобы что-то делать при переходе пользователем по ссылке, нужно сделать цикл асинхронным.

```
while True:
   ...
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    ...
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Если кратко, Flask не поддерживает асинхронность, используй либо [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), либо [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). По-другому никак.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Через threading сделал